Changing the pixel value of Copernicus Browser raster data from RGB to the displayed ones in Copernicus Browser
I have a raster data of Moisture Index downloaded from Copernicus Browser, the problem is the pixel value is the RGB value not the moisture index value. Then i tried the stretched symbology and its even worse when its only takes one band as a pixel value.

How do i change the pixel value so it will change to the desired legend such as the one from Copernicus Browser?


You downloaded an RGB render of the dataset probably in JPG or PNG format, not the dataset itself.
It is technically possible to convert it back to the index values at a reduced accuracy and with much work. I suggest you use the Copernicus Browser to search for the satellite imagery of your area and time frame, download the imagery, and calculate the NDMI yourself.
NDMI is calculated from Sentinel-2 mission data. I suggest using the L2A level of processing.
The equation for calculating NDMI using this data is:
Sentinel-2 NDMI = (B08 - B11) / (B08 + B11) (ref)

I downloaded the data in TIFF format tho, is there a way to prevent this or i should only use the data from the search option?

You can download raw bands from the tab where you downloaded the visualization. This option reduces the resolution for larger areas.

okay then thank you for the advice
